# Angular and requirejs, provider with injectors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I had a working version of my app that I a trying to now split up into requirejs modules. I am having some trouble getting a provider that has some injectors to work. It seems when I brought it into require js, it does not want to inject my provider properly. I could use some help, this one has me stumped.

Here's what I mean -

The provider -

```
  define('test/my-provider',['angular',
     'test/my-factory'
 ],
 function myProvider(angular, MYfactory) {
     var metadata = {
         componentName: 'myProvider',
         moduleName: 'test.myProvider'
     };
     var $moduleObjectProvider;

     $moduleObjectProvider.$inject = [];

     $moduleObjectProvider = function() {
         var trackConstructor = {};

         this.moduleConstructor = function(name, cb) {
            //constructor
         };

         var $get;
         this.$get = $get;

         $get.$inject = ['URLfactory', '$log', '$location'];

         $get = function(URLfactory, $log, $location) {
             return {
                 function1: function(var1) {

                 },
                 function2: function(var1, var2) {

                 },
                 function3: function() {

                 }
             };
         };
     };
     //metadata.componentName ?
     angular.module(metadata.moduleName, []).provider(metadata.componentName, $moduleObjectProvider);

     return metadata;
 }
```

);

The issue I am having is with the injectors -

```
   TypeError: Cannot set property '$inject' of undefined
```

which points to the line containing

```
  $moduleObjectProvider.$inject = [];
```

One thing worth mentioning is I changed the format of the top bit (JSlinter was yelling at me). When it was working previous to turning it into requirejs format, the top bit looked like this :

```
   $moduleObjectProvider.$inject = [];

function $moduleObjectProvider() {
```

It seems to be hitting everything fine, the injector is having a problem here (I think). I have hit a wall here - would be great if someone could shed some light on the situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your do `var myFunction = function(){}` your function is not 'hoisted' to the top. So it is undefined when setting the $inject array. Change it to `function myFunction(){}` and you should be fine.